# Can I decrease socket address in use time?

Tags: linux, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi is hosting a python asyncore server, and a few arduino's connect to it via LAN. We have the server almost bug free, but when something goes wrong and the server crashes, when restarting the server it says that the address is in use. We coded it so that, if the address is in use it will just keep retrying until the address is set free, but this takes quite a long time.

Now I heard that you can edit the time before an address gets set free in Linux.
For instance, on my macbook the socket address gets set free after like 10 seconds.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use shutdown instead of close method (if this is a case) to perform immediately releasing resources:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.6.shtml

Also, following settings from socket call can be helpful http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html:

- SO_REUSEADDR
- SO_REUSEPORT
- SO_RCVTIMEO
- SO_SNDTIMEO

Comment: We already do that, but when something does go wrong, which can always happen, we need to be able to get the server back up as fast as possible. Thanks for your answer though, it might work with an try except around the entire code and on an exception we will first close the socket that way and then restart the server.

Comment: also, it says that 'socket.shutdown()' closes the connection in a timely fashion, which doesn't necessarily mean immediately.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "get server back up as fast.." but perhaps you should read man of socket http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html and have a look on following: SO_REUSEADDR SO_REUSEPORT  SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO

Comment: thanks! I'll look into that. With "get the server back up as fast.." I mean getting the server back online as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Running an example several times with too small delay between executions, could lead to this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This is because the previous execution has left the socket in a TIME_WAIT state, and can’t be immediately reused.

There is a socket flag to set, in order to prevent this, socket.SO_REUSEADDR:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

the SO_REUSEADDR flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in TIME_WAITstate, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire.

source[->](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown)